# Request Parameter order in Servlet Containers

Tags: java, servlets

Apparently the order of request parameters is not preserved in the Tomcat servlet container (per google it seems other containers share the same problem).

This seems very wrong.

How would one restore the actual order of request parameters from a HttpServletRequest?

**EDIT**
BTW for those that think order for request parameters does not matter there is a difference between:

```
http://blah?a=1&a=2
```

and

```
http://blah?a=2&a=1
```

So order does matter for duplicate request parameters (luckily Java does handle this right).

Comment: why would you need the order of the parameters? you can access everyone using its name

Comment: Because the order of the parameters could be used to indicate the order of a list ie sorted/linkedhashmap. I'm sure you have needed a sorted tuple once? I didn't want to rely on name mangling the request parameters to do order.

Comment: I second the notion that relying on anything from a client is a Bad Idea; there are just too many ways that could go wrong.

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't say it was a good idea to rely on it. I think its  just odd that request parameter order matters (for duplicate request parameters hence String[] for getParameterValues()) and then it doesn't matter (getParameterMap()). For example the  HttpServletRequest API has a call getParameterNames(). It should return a Set not an ordered Enumeration (I realize this is because its just an old API).

Comment: @DaveNewton Also parameter order such as "a[]=1&a[]=2" is relied on all the time in PHP/Rails programming: see http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/jquery-14-param-demystified/

Comment: But... that has nothing to do with your post, since AFAICT you were asking about servlet containers; perhaps I misunderstood the question's tags. Also, none of this deals with client-level parameter ordering, which is another variable to keep in mind.

Comment: Yeah it got completely off topic. Apologies. But I do say you have to "rely" on the client doing something right and order (as with the case of duplicate parameters) can be important and it is not unreasonable to ask such. I don't know of a browser or REST client that does not maintain order (even non duplicate parameters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you should not depend on the order of parameters. If you are really sure this is necessary, you can:

- use `request.getQueryString()` to see `GET` parameters
- get the raw request (`request.getInputStream()`) and read the submitted `POST` params.

Comment: I did try request.getInputStream() and it didn't work (some filter upstream must have eaten the goods). I was relying on the request order because I was lazy and I was shocked to find out about this.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a filter - it will be the servlet engine itself consuming the input stream when it parses the POST parameters, as soon as you call `getParameter()` et.al. at least once. Citing the [servlet api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter(java.lang.String)): _If the parameter data was sent in the request body, such as occurs with an HTTP POST request, then reading the body directly via getInputStream() or getReader() can interfere with the execution of this method._

Answer (score 0):

You likely could use the getRequestURL: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL() and from there parse out the parameters.

BUT, in reply to your comment "This seems very wrong.", I think you should rethink your stance.

Ordering your parameters simply doesn't make sense.  Lets say - for example - you were asking for a list of cars based on parameters.  It shouldn't matter if you're asking for a list of fords that are green or a list of green cars that are fords.

Comment: No but lets say I was making a TODO list that I wanted to update all at once (I'm not doing this BTW). Each parameter name might be the id of the entry. The value would be the description. The ORDER of the parameters would be the priority. I'm not sayings its robust... I was just expecting this for a quick hack and its the first time I found out about this.