# Saving several checkbox inputs as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Ive got whole bunch of checkbox inputs which all have same name attribute. I want to save their values (1 if checked, also 0 if not because order matters, I need to output them in right order) as an array which is not going as expected.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-a"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-b"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-c"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" id="feature-d"/>
```

etc

---

```
foreach( $_POST['feature'] as $feature ) {

    if( isset( $feature ) && '' !== $feature ) {
        $feature = 1; 
    }
    else {
        $feature = '';
    } 

    $features = array();
    array_push($features, $feature);
}
update_term_meta( $term_id, 'features', $features );

//This always outputs a:1 {i:0;i:1;} for some reason! No matter what I check
```

**What am I missing?**

1. I tried to add `feature[]` as name attribute
2. I tried to assing '' or "" to `$feature`

Nothing is working. Is there a mistake in my loop I can't see?

Comment: 1) You need to apply `feature[]` as a `name` attribute. 2) As you were not applying any values to your checkboxes then when you select checkboxes it'll pass an array of `selected` checkboxes with a value of `Yes` and you'll not receive those values which aren't `checked`

Comment: I updated my code, please have a look.

Comment: You won't get those values which are not checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How get value for unchecked checkbox in checkbox elements when form posted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted) Also check [post the checkboxes that are unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809494/post-the-checkboxes-that-are-unchecked)

Comment: So, there's no way to save checkboxes as an array with certain order? I mean situations where unchecked boxes also matter. Also,  I ALWAYS get the same output as in code's comment, no matter what boxes I check, even if 10 checkboxes - still the same.

Comment: Please check my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304601/saving-several-checkbox-inputs-as-an-array?noredirect=1#comment56351344_34304601) for you first question. And for second one you need to post the values that you were getting within your `$_POST` method `checked` and `unchecked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach( $_POST['feature'] as $feature ) {

```
if( isset( $feature ) && $feature !=='' ) {
    $feature = 1; 
}
else {
    $feature = 0;
} 

$features = array();
array_push($features, $feature);
```

}
update_term_meta( $term_id, 'features', $features );