# How to get values from unchecked checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I am working on an attendance reporting page. Here I am creating a dynamic checkbox with content from db.

I can store the checked student(present) students detail, but I also want to store the absent student. In order to do that I want a hidden field or something to get the unchecked student details please anyone help me to do that.

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" summary="">
        <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>" name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>" checked="checked"> 
                    <?php echo $row['st_name'] ; ?>
                    <label for="input<?php echo $row['st_id']; ?>"></label>
                    <input type="text" name="absent" value="0"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    </div>
```

PHP code

```
<?php   
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `student_info` WHERE `sem`='$selsem'");   
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    //Here goes array
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['student']);$i++)
    {  
        $id=$_POST['student'][$i];
        echo $id;
        $check=1;
       mysql_query("insert into manage_attendance(st_id,date,sem,period,subject,status) values('$id','$seldate','$selsem','$selperiod','$selsub','$check')");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can't you just list the `checked`(present) students and then remove them from all students and then create the absent student list from it?

Comment: its a good idea but i am using an array for storing present students id....so how can i select the absent student using sql command....

Comment: Do you have any estimation of how many present students can be at max?

Comment: no.may vary according to table in db

Comment: OK, if they are not a huge number then you can create a comma separated list of them and then use the same query as the one which are using to create the checkboxes and add a `where st_id not in (your_comma_separated_list)`(or something like this) to generate a list of all students minus present students which I assume will be absent students.

Comment: now,I am trying exactly like you said...

Comment: I tried like this but not working.                                                                                                                $ans=array();
 $ans=$_POST['student'];
 print_r($ans);
 $re=mysql_query("SELECT `st_id`
          FROM `student_info` 
         WHERE `st_id` NOT IN (' . implode(',',array_map('intval', $ans)) . ')");
  while ($ro = mysql_fetch_assoc($re)){
   $ro['st_id'];  }

Comment: @SibyXavier - mysql_* is now deprcated. You shld instead be using mysqli_* or PDO. Please see [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Comment: this will use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted

Comment: I have solved the problem>Thankyou @EhsanT for your idea....

Comment: Good, you are welcome. and also as @Landslyde suggested please consider using either `mysqli` or `PDO` since `mysql` is deprecated and it's beside that, it's really vulnerable.

Comment: okay i will do that.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @EhsanT said i have solved the problem with sql command...Thankyou EhsanT....

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $ans=array();
    $ans=$_POST['student'];
    $re=mysql_query("SELECT `st_id` FROM `student_info` 
     WHERE `sem` ='$selsem'
  AND `st_id` NOT IN (".implode(',',array_map('intval',$ans)).")");
    while ($ro = mysql_fetch_row($re)){
     mysql_query("insert into manage_attendance(st_id,date,sem,period,subject,status) values('$ro[0]','$seldate','$selsem','$selperiod','$selsub','0')");  } 
    //Here goes array
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['student']);$i++)
    {  
        $id=$_POST['student'][$i];
        //echo $id;
        $check=1;

       mysql_query("insert into manage_attendance(st_id,date,sem,period,subject,status) values('$id','$seldate','$selsem','$selperiod','$selsub','$check')");
        //print_r ($_POST['student']);

    }
}
```