# checkbox not registering when unchecked php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a pretty basic function on my website where a user ticks a box, and if the box is ticked, it will carry out a query and unset a session. If it's not, it won't execute the query, but it will destroy the session.

It's pretty basic, but for some reason, PHP isn't registering if the checkbox is unchecked. It will work if it is checked, just not the latter.

This is my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    $la = ($_POST['la'] == "on") ? 1 : 0; // if the box is checked, return 1. if not, return 0
    if($la == 1 || $la == 0){
        if($la == 1){
            // where I execute the query...
            session_start();
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            redirect('./');
            exit();
        } else if($la == 0) {
            session_start();
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            redirect('./');
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        redirect('./');
    }
}
```

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted

Comment: When HTML submit a form in POST|GET it does not submit unchecked check boxes, so you need to check in your PHP code isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])

Comment: @Faraz it seems to work in other areas of my site?

Comment: @Faraz also, check line 2

Comment: If you only have checkbox in that form so it might be empty as nothing else is sumited, submit a hidden value in form to make sure when form is submited its not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code see if it works-

```
<?php
session_start();//session start should be in the beginning of the code
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
        $la = isset($_POST['la']) ? 1 : 0; // if the box is checked, return 1. if not, return 0
        if($la == 1 || $la == 0){
            if($la == 1){
                // where I execute the query...                
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
                redirect('./');
                exit();
            } else if($la == 0) {                
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
                redirect('./');
                exit();
            }
        } else {
            redirect('./');
        }
    }
```

Comment: var_dump($_POST) while unchecking the checkbox

Comment: fixed it! misspelled something.. haha thankyou for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, checkbox when not selected directly not send the variable.
This variable $_POST['la'] when you not selected not send.
Maybe you need use this code to control this case:

```
if (isset($_POST['la'])) {
    ...
}
```