# Why my data is always true, and checkboxes returns always "YES"?

Tags: php, mysql, post

`$data` is always `true` and checkboxes return always `"YES"`. How to solve this problem?

```
function yesNo($data){
    if($data){
        return "YES";
    }else{
        return "NO";
    }
}
```

Checkboxes here:

```
$txt.="Rozpoczynam działalność gospodarczą: ".yesNo($_POST['indywidualne'])."<br>";
if(!isset($_POST['komunikacja'])||!trim($_POST['komunikacja'])){
    $result = array( 'type' => 'error', 'code' => "podaj komunikacje");
    endSend($result);
}
$txt.="Chce rozliczać się w terminach kwartalnych: ".yesNo($_POST['komunikacja'])."<br>";
if(!isset($_POST['firmowe'])||!trim($_POST['firmowe'])){
    $result = array( 'type' => 'error', 'code' => "podaj rodzaj rozliczenia o");
    endSend($result);
}
$txt.="Płatnik VAT: ".yesNo($_POST['firmowe'])."<br>";
if(!isset($_POST['ewidencja'])||!trim($_POST['ewidencja'])){
    $result = array( 'type' => 'error', 'code' => "podaj email");
    endSend($result);
}
```

Checkbox in html:

```
          <label for="checkbox-vat">
              <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-vat"> Płatnik VAT
          </label>
          <label for="checkbox-activity">
              <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-activity"> Rozpoczynam działalność gospodarczą
          </label>
          <label for="checkbox-quarterly">
              <input type="checkbox" name="" id="checkbox-quarterly"> Chce rozliczać się w terminach kwartalnych
          </label>
```

Comment: why are you using double `!!` in if condition?

Comment: I forgot to edit the code before I put it here, I use ($ data)

Comment: you have no name attr (`name=""`)? surely you're not even passing data properly, you should `print_r` or `var_dump` `$data` inside the `yesNo` function and see what it says

Answer (score 6):

As I have seen, you are passing some value in `$data` variable. And the IF condition considers it as a value, any in IF statement will treat as a TRUE.

Checkbox returns the value `YES` or `NO`. The value of checkbox `YES` or `NO` for `IF statement` is always TRUE.

Just change to:

```
    function yesNo($data){
    // echo $data;die; //uncomment this statement to see $data value
        if(strtolower($data)=='yes'){
            return "YES";
        }else{
            return "NO";
        }
    }
```

Suppose you have checkbox field as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_yes" value="yes" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_no" value="no" />
```

You will receive checkbox value as `yes` or `no`. Please put your checkbox field here or write what value you have given for it.

**Updated Answer:** If checked the checkbox, you will get checkbox value if not then the checkbox name does not exist in `$_POST` or `$_GET` data array.
As I have seen you didn't provide name and value for checkboxes. So your case the checkboxes names and values do not exist in  `$_POST` or `$_GET` data array.

[The best example of how to use checkboxes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted)

Comment: Now it's always "NO"

Comment: Please echo `$data` in function and see what value it has and then put condition according to that value.

Comment: Probably put echo in the wrong place because nothing is displayed, as i said, im new

Comment: Are you able to echo $data value?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying, but I really can't find where it's shown

Comment: Can you share checkbox fields here?

Comment: I've shared at the top

Comment: when I changed from "on" to "yes" it returns always "NO"

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239536/how-get-value-for-unchecked-checkbox-in-checkbox-elements-when-form-posted

Answer (score 0):

If your code doesn't display any error, it means you checkbox is always passing some value to post. You should check first if the post index is set

`yesNo( isset($_POST['indywidualne']) )`

Comment: Still always "YES"

Comment: this will always pass - isset() will just check if var is set, and it always will be (regardless of checkbox value)

Comment: @pomor eh, u dont have name in your checkboxes? $_POST is using input's name attribute as index. where do u even get the index "indywidualne, komunikacja, etc"?