# How to get all the form parameters in a servlet in the order in which the input elements have been arranged in the form?

Tags: forms, servlets

I am currently using request.getParameterMap() to get the map of all the name-value pairs of the form elements entered. I need these elements in the same order as in the form html that is being submitted. Map doesn't preserve the order at all times. Getting all the form name-value pairs in the order in which its arranged in the form html is very pivotal for my application to work. How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request Parameter order in Servlet Containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813803/request-parameter-order-in-servlet-containers)